# Why is a regex matched string behaving oddly?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a piece of code as shown below :

```
    let regex = /^[^aeiou]+(?=[aeiou])/;
    let regexStr = "hhhhello".match(regex);
    console.log(regexStr.length); // prints 1
```

Shouldn't it print 4? However if I add a "" to regexStr, it shows the right value.

```
    let regex = /^[^aeiou]+(?=[aeiou])/;
    let regexStr = "hhhhello".match(regex) + "";
    console.log(regexStr.length); // prints 4
```

Can someone explain what's happening?

Comment: not sure, i think you have to do something similar `("hhhhello").match (regex);` or `var str = "hhhhello";` then `str.match(regex)` not "hhhhello".match(regex);

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `regexStr` is an array with one element, the string `hhhh`. By adding a string you implicitly convert to string, which then has length 4. You could just use `regexStr[0].length`.

Answer (score 1):

Because string.match() actually returns an array of all matched values. In your case, it is only 1.

When you add the "" it is instead converted into a string value.

For more info you can check these [docs on string.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Answer (score 0):

The `/^[^aeiou]+(?=[aeiou])/` regex only matches **a single chunk** of 1+ chars other than `a`, `e`, `i`, `o`, `u` that are followed with a  `a`, `e`, `i`, `o` or `u` letters, at the start of string.

You may use

```js
let regex = /[^aeiou](?=[^aeiou]*[aeiou])/gy; 
let regexStr = "hhhhello".match(regex);
console.log(regexStr.length); // prints 4, regexStr = ["h", "h", "h", "h"]
```

The `/[^aeiou](?=[^aeiou]*[aeiou])/gy` matches only from the start of string thanks to the `y` *sticky* modifier, while `g` will make it match multiple times till the first failure.

- `[^aeiou]` - matches 1 char other than `a`, `e`, `i`, `o` and `u`
- `(?=[^aeiou]*[aeiou])` - if it is immediately followed with any 0 or more occurrences of these chars followed with 1 letter, `a`, `e`, `i`, `o` or `u`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QCJwto/1).